# how to hide keyboard of textview even though if the editing mode enabled

Tags: uitextview, uikeyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to disable uikeyboard of textview ,if the editing mode enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105619/how-to-disable-uikeyboard-of-textview-if-the-editing-mode-enabled)

How to disable or hide keyboard of UITextView.

Even though the editing mode is enabled.